# blacklisted URLs: what to trust?

Tags: malware

This website blacklists URLs: http://hosts-file.net/?s=54.244&view=history&direct=1 Its last database update has been today. When I check the last 5 URLs it published Firefox tells me they are unsafe. But When I check those URLs on http://wepawet.cs.ucsb.edu/ it says they are benign. And when I run those URLs on my computer (i take a risk) by unchecking the boxes of Firefox that prevent from blacklisted websites nothing happens: which result to trust ?

Comment: Please can you explain why you are trying to figure this out and it might help us to answer a little better. Do you have any reason to doubt the first site? Are these URLs particularly important to you? We need a little more info to go off...

Comment: @TimC I  just want to write an article about blacklisted URLs, so I find these contradictions.

Comment: Since these are two separate services you cannot assume they will give you the same results. It all depends on when and how that specific entity detects and flags malicious URLs. From what I can see you are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @ilikebeets Yes, but the problem is that one service says it is too dangerous and the other says it is benign:  is science politics and not real facts any more ?

Comment: Just like every other field in the world, security is seen in different ways by people. Some people classify some threats higher than others do. Can you check what is the criteria for their classification? This might explain why you are seeing this behaviour. 

Also, what do you expect to happen after your open the url on your computer? If you expect your computer to blow up, it won't. The website could simply be delivering some malware to your computer which you won't know about until a scan finds it.

Comment: A good example of how a range of different results can be given for a single URL would be to scan it with VirusTotal (www.virustotal.com). You'll notice that from the 20+ systems used for scanning the outcome ranges from Malicious to Phishing to Clear to Unknown etc. It's all to do with what that specific entity knows about it. If you ask n systems to scan a URL you can potentially get n + 1 different results for that URL.

Comment: @trustme Mind giving me the URLs so i can do some research on them and give you a good answer?

Comment: @BigBob1000 Thank you. Here it is: www.lpmxp625.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@trustme lpmxp625.com is a malware link so lets first start by finding out how i came to that conclusion.

If we do a Google search for that link* (The star indicates a link listed below) we find the first 100 results coming back as people asking how to remove lpmxp625 from their PCs which brings up red flags in my mind. Now we go to [VirusTotal.com](http://VirusTotal.com) lets run a scan on the link**. After scanning the link 4 out of 50 antivirus engines comes back as saying its malicious with BitDefender leading the way. BitDefender has 98% detection from most tests***. We will continue on doing more tests with Sucuri which is a website scanner but it comes back with even more bad news for that domain****. We can scan with more scanners and tools but they all come back with bad news.

I personally use hosts-file.net for blocking malware/ad blocking i find it to be highly reliable for blocking malware and ads. I also use other lists as well. Most of these list are composed by volunteers who actively try to find malware so that other users don't get infected.

https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=lpmxp625.com&oq=lpmxp625.com&gs_l=hp.3...2108.12684.0.13417.6.6.0.0.0.0.121.396.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1j2.51.hp..6.0.0.0.G1fjtGRXyNg

https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/a8c9a4ae305969b7305b85d378eaf45dc147d9b43a12e88c5fe76d2b7cf56d76/analysis/

[https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&q=bitdefender+wins&oq=bitdefender+wins&gs_l=serp.3...19756.34772.0.35011.14.10.4.0.0.0.73.642.10.10.0....0...1c.1.51.serp..1.13.603.1zCnWd1mqWA](https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&q=bitdefender%20wins&oq=bitdefender%20wins&gs_l=serp.3...19756.34772.0.35011.14.10.4.0.0.0.73.642.10.10.0....0...1c.1.51.serp..1.13.603.1zCnWd1mqWA)

http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/lpmxp625.com

Hope that helps.